# Specific problem with redirecting to same page but from different locations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have homepage and this is controller to retrieve it:

```
@GetMapping("/homePage")
public String index(Model model, Principal principal) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);

    return "homepage";
}
```

That works fine.

So, I'm right now on Home page and trying to go on

```
/api/transaction/userTransactions/{userId}
```

I have two links on homepage:

```
<li> <a th:href="@{/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/{userId} (userId=${userId})}">Wallets</a></li>
<li> <a th:href="@{/api/transaction/userTransactions/{userId} (userId=${userId})}">Transactions</a</li>
```

When I click on link that says `Transaction` I'm redirected to `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/userTransactions/1` that is good.

Now, when I click on first link, for `Wallets` I'm redirected to `Wallets` page and this is controller for that page:

```
@GetMapping("/userWallet/balance/{user_id}")
@PreAuthorize("#user_id == authentication.principal.id")
public String getUserWallet(@PathVariable(value = "user_id") Long user_id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("wallet", walletService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id));
    model.addAttribute("wallets", walletService.netWorth(user_id));
    return "user_profile";
}
```

Inside that page, I again have two links: Now one link is for `homepage` and second is again for `transaction` page.

```
<li><a id="wallets" th:href="@{/api/test/homePage}">Home</a></li>
<li><a th:href="@{/api/transaction/userTransactions/{userId} (userId=${userId})}">Transactions</a></li>
```

When I now click on link for `Transaction` I'm being redirected to `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/userTransactions/` as you can see, without `id` at the end.

So, when I'm on home page and try to go on this URL

```
"@{/api/transaction/userTransactions/{userId} (userId=${userId})}"
```

It works, and I get `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/userTransactions/1` but when I'm on another page, as I mentioned above, on `Wallet` page for example and try to go on

```
"@{/api/transaction/userTransactions/{userId} (userId=${userId})}"
```

I'm redirected to `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/userTransactions/`

This is controller that should return `transaction` page:

```
@GetMapping("/userTransactions/{user_id}")
public String getUserTransactions(@PathVariable("user_id") long user_id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("transactions", transactionService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id));
    return "transactions";
}
```

I really don't know what to try and what can be the problem since both links are the same but from one page link works and from another page link doesn't work, despite they are same totally.

Comment: You've added the user id to the model `model.addAttribute("userId", userId);` on the homepage, but not the wallet page.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem! Thanks!